# Type Error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, symfony

I am trying to implement my search function from my Symfony 6 API into my React table. When I click on search I get the a 200 response from the server but immediately after that I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Why is that?

This is my client code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Modal, Button, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import BorderColorIcon from '@material-ui/icons/BorderColor';
import { Edit } from "../../components/Edit";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import brand from 'boss-api/dummy/brand';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { SourceReader, PapperBlock } from 'boss-components';

const styles = ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  button: {
    margin: '1rem',
  },
  modal: {
    margin: 'auto',
    maxWidth: 600,
    width: '90%',
    height: '100%'
  },
  paper: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    boxShadow: '5px 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)',
    padding: '2rem',
    borderRadius: '5px',
  },
  textField: {
    marginBottom: '1rem',
  },
});

function Gebruiker2(props) {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
  const [usernameSearch, setUsernameSearch] = useState('');
  const { classes } = props;
  const [newUser, setNewUser] = useState({
    firstName: '',
    email: '',
    phoneNumber: '',
    street: '',
    houseNumber: '',
    postalCode: '',
    city: '',
    province: '',
    roleName: '',
    username: '',
    password: ''
    });



    const handleAddUser = () => {
      setOpenModal(true);
    };
  
    const handleCloseModal = () => {
      setOpenModal(false);
    };

    const handleChange = (event) => {
      const { name, value } = event.target;
      setNewUser(prevUser => ({
        ...prevUser,
        [name]: value,
      }));
    };
    
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://127.0.0.1:8000/users')
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => setUsers(data.personInfo))
      .catch(error => console.log(exrror));
  }, []);

  const onAdd = () => {
    fetch('https://127.0.0.1:8000/register', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(newUser)
    })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        handleCloseModal(); // Close the modal after the user has been added
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  };  ;

  const onEdit = async (id, name, email) => {
    await fetch(`https://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/edit/${id}`, {
      method: "PUT",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: name,
        email: email
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      }
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status !== 200) {
          return;
        } else {
          return response.json();
        }
      })
      .then((data) => {
        // setUsers((users) => [...users, data]);
        const updatedUsers = users?.map((user) => {
          if (user.id === id) {
            user.name = name;
            user.email = email;
          }
        
          return user;
        });
        

        setUsers((users) => updatedUsers);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };

  const onDelete = (id) => {
    fetch(`https://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/delete/${id}`, {
      method: 'DELETE',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        const updatedUsers = users.filter(user => user.id !== id);
        setUsers(updatedUsers); // Remove the deleted user from the state
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  };

  const handleSearch = () => {
    fetch(`https://127.0.0.1:8000/users/search`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ username: usernameSearch }),
    })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        if (Array.isArray(data)) {
          setUsers(data.personInfo)
        } else {
          console.log("Invalid response format");
        }
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  };
  
  const handleSearchInputChange = (event) => {
    setUsernameSearch(event.target.value);
  };
  
  
  

    return (
      <>
        <div className="App">
        <PapperBlock whiteBg icon="ion-ios-create-outline" title="In-Row Editable Cell" desc="The Editable Table Cell supports editing features including creating, updating and deleting rows. The editing state contains information about rows currently being edited, changes applied to a particular row, and rows that have been deleted and created.">
          <Button className={classes.button} variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleAddUser}>Add New User</Button>
          <TextField
          label="Search by username"
          variant="outlined"
          value={usernameSearch}
          onChange={handleSearchInputChange}
          className={classes.textField}
        />

        <Button onClick={handleSearch}>Search</Button>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {users.map((user) => (
                <tr key={user.id}>
                  <td>{user.id}</td>
                  <td>{user.name}</td>
                  <td>{user.email}</td>
                  <td>
                    <Edit
                      id={user.id}
                      name={user.name}
                      email={user.email}
                      onEdit={onEdit}
                      onDelete={onDelete}
                    />
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
          </PapperBlock>
        </div>

      <Modal
      open={openModal}
      onClose={handleCloseModal}
      className={classes.modal}
      >
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <h2>Add New User</h2>
        <TextField
        className={classes.textField}
        label="First Name"
        name="first_name"
        value={newUser.first_name}
        onChange={handleChange}
        fullWidth
      />
      <TextField
        className={classes.textField}
        label="Email"
        name="email"
        value={newUser.email}
        onChange={handleChange}
        fullWidth
      />
      <TextField
        className={classes.textField}
        label="Phone Number"
        name="phone_number"
        value={newUser.phone_number}
        onChange={handleChange}
        fullWidth
      />
      <TextField
        className={classes.textField}
        label="Street"
        name="street"
        value={newUser.street}
        onChange={handleChange}
        fullWidth
      />
      <TextField
        className={classes.textField}
        label="House Number"
        name="house_number"
        value={newUser.house_number}
        onChange={handleChange}
        fullWidth
      />
      <TextField
        className={classes.textField}
        label="Postal Code"
        name="postal_code"
        value={newUser.postal_code}
        onChange={handleChange}
        fullWidth
      />
      <TextField
        className={classes.textField}
        label="City"
        name="city"
        value={newUser.city}
        onChange={handleChange}
        fullWidth
      />
      <TextField
        className={classes.textField}
        label="Province"
        name="province"
        value={newUser.province}
        onChange={handleChange}
        fullWidth
      />
      <TextField
        className={classes.textField}
        label="Role Name"
        name="role_name"
        value={newUser.role_name}
        onChange={handleChange}
        fullWidth
      />


      <TextField
      className={classes.textField}
      label="Username"
      name="username"
      value={newUser.username}
      onChange={handleChange}
      fullWidth
      />
      <TextField
      className={classes.textField}
      label="Password"
      name="password"
      value={newUser.password}
      onChange={handleChange}
      fullWidth
      />
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={onAdd}>Save</Button>{' '}
        <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleCloseModal}>Cancel</Button>
      </div>
      </Modal>
     
      </>
       );
}



Gebruiker2.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Gebruiker2);
```

Symfony 6 Controller

```
<?php 

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use App\Entity\PersonInfo;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class UserController extends AbstractController
{
    private $entityManager;
    
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    //function to retrieve the personInfo object from the database
    public function showAllUsersAndPersons()
    {
        // setting $personRepository to repository from the PersonInfo Class
        $personRepository = $this->entityManager->getRepository(PersonInfo::class);
        //in the personInfo Repo we run the findAll function which retrieves the data from the db
        $personList = $personRepository->findAll();
        
        // we set the data into array
        $data = array(
            'personInfo' => $personList
        );
        
        //return the array
        return $this->json($data);
    }

    public function searchUsers(Request $request, UserRepository $userRepository): JsonResponse
    {
        $requestData = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
    
        $name = $requestData['username'] ?? null;
        $email = $requestData['email'] ?? null;
    
        if (!$name && !$email) {
            return new JsonResponse(['error' => 'At least one of username or email is required'], 400);
        }
    
        $users = $userRepository->createQueryBuilder('u');
    
        if ($name && !$email) {
            $users->where('u.username LIKE :name')
                ->setParameter('name', '%'.$name.'%');
        } elseif (!$name && $email) {
            $users->where('u.email LIKE :email')
                ->setParameter('email', '%'.$email.'%');
        } else {
            $users->where('u.username LIKE :name AND u.email LIKE :email')
                ->setParameter('name', '%'.$name.'%')
                ->setParameter('email', '%'.$email.'%');
        }
    
        $users = $users->getQuery()->getResult();
    
        if (empty($users)) {
            return new JsonResponse(['error' => 'No matching users found'], 404);
        }
    
        $responseData = [];
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            if ($name && !$email) {
                $responseData[] = [
                    'username' => $user->getUsername(),
                ];
            } elseif (!$name && $email) {
                $responseData[] = [
                    'email' => $user->getEmail(),
                ];
            } else {
                $responseData[] = [
                    'id' => $user->getId(),
                    'username' => $user->getUsername(),
                    'email' => $user->getEmail(),
                ];
            }
        }
    
        return $this->json($responseData);
    }
    

    
    

}






?>
```

Comment: You could make your example a lot easier to read by only including relevant details, instead of posting everything... The style information is certainly irrelevant to start with.
If you get an error message, it's usually associated with a particular line of code, but you haven't included that in your question.

Comment: You remembered to use conditional chaining in your functions, but are still trying to directly access `users.map` in your JSX; that's going to error out until the users data arrives asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

check array length in your table body

```
<tbody>
   {users.length > 0 && users?.map((user) => ()}
</tbody>
```